# Correct Face Attributes not working

Tags: materials, shaders, procedural

I'm trying to create a mesh with a procedural checkerboard shader, but when I scale the mesh, the material scales as well, even when I have Correct Face Attributes applied. Oddly, it seems to work correctly in Edit Mode, but as soon as I jump back to Object Mode, the shatter gets stretched and stays that way.

I have tried scaling the mesh and applying the scale both before and after I assign the material, and assigning the material and then scaling. I have tried both moving a face, and scaling, both in Edit Mode.

What can I do to get the mesh to sale without affecting the material?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Correct Face Attributes* is supposed to work in *Edit* mode. To do what you want to do, you can choose the *Object* output of the *Texture Coordinate* and choose an empty as *Object*:

[image]

It's the empty that is now determining the texture projection, if you move the object, the texture stays still:

[image]

Comment: That worked. Thank you!